# How to Set Breakpoint in WinDbg on api-ms-* Calls in Windows 10

Tags: winapi, windbg

For example IDA Pro shows import table containing function CheckTokenMembership in library api-ms-win-security-base-l1-2-0

Checking MSDN info for API call https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx it says it is in advapi32.dll

However trying

bp advapi32!CheckTokenMembership

Results in error Couldn't resolve error at 'advapi32!CheckTokenMembership'

Answer (score 2):

`CheckTokenMembership` is and always will be exported by advapi32.dll. The problem is that WinDbg uses the symbol name if you have symbols for said module.

What I would do is type `bp ADVAPI32!CheckTokenMembership` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and you should end up with `bp ADVAPI32!CheckTokenMembershipStub`. This trick does not work for everything, sometimes you have to figure out the forward yourself or take a peek at the ntdll.dll and kernelbase.dll exports.

api- files do not contain code, they are just a layering exercise that Microsoft is forcing on everyone for some reason. I believe they are a result of the [MinWin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin) experiment and they might possibly some day contain code but even then kernel32 and friends will still have forwarders to maintain compatibility so there is no reason for anyone outside Microsoft to use the api- files (IMHO).

Comment: The decomposition of user (and kernel) exports into *api-ms-\*.dll* files is part of establishing API sets. This is an engineering effort that builds the foundation for having Windows run on *any* device, and it is essentially, what enables the Universal Windows Platform. It allows running the same code on a PC, tablet, phone, HoloLens, IoT device, Xbox, etc.

Comment: API sets aren't generally implemented as real files. The loader maps them to the implementation DLL based on the mapping in apisetschema.dll. (Currently on Windows 10 systems, apisetschema.dll is typically the only "api*.dll" file in System32.) Linking wth mincore.lib or onecore.lib will use API sets.

Answer (score 0):

I verified on a crash dump file that advapi32.dll exports the CheckTokenMembership function, so setting a breakpoint should be possible. It's likely in your scenario the module has not yet been loaded, so how about trying 'bu' instead? From WinDbg help:

- The bu (Set Unresolved Breakpoint) command sets a deferred or unresolved breakpoint. A bu breakpoint is set on a symbolic reference to the breakpoint location that is specified in the command (not on an address) and is activated whenever the module with the reference is resolved. For more information about these breakpoints, see Unresolved Breakpoints (bu Breakpoints).

> 76b51ca2          advapi32!CheckTokenMembership ()